# Java source won't compile as soon as I put it in a package?

Tags: java, maven, package

I installed Maven on my archlinux desktop.
I have a perplexing issue.

Following the getting started guide and installing Maven, at the end of it all
I had the default company set to zerovector (instead of my-company.)
So the directory structure (and package) looks like this:
`src/com/zerovector/app (or com.zerovector.app)`

App just says `"Hello World"`
mvn compile fails. mvn build fails. `NoClassDefFound` errors when I try to run
the product of Maven's processes.
Trying to compile it manually `(javac App.java)` fails with `NoClassDefFound`.
As soon as I remove the `package com.zerovector.app;` line suddenly it compiles and works.
I can go `javac App.java` and it compiles just fine into `App.class` (simple Hello World prog.)
And this `App.class` does it's little `"Hello World"` and exits fine.

Why is the package line throwing java for a bunch of nonesense? Can I fix this or am
I going to have to manually code/organize and forget Maven and Packages?

Comment: NoClassDefFound isn't a *compilation* error - it's a *runtime* error (an exception)... it's very unclear what's actually happening here. But your source structure *should* match the package structure - it's not clear whether or not that that's the case here.

Comment: Maven expects sources in src/main/java by default, not in src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Maven, the Java class code should be in the directory `src/main/java/com/zerovector/app` and not in `src/com/zerovector/app`. If you don't want to use the default source directory you have to change the configuration.

If you use `javac` then don't change your current directory to `src/main/java/com/zerovector/app` but stay in the source root directory:

```
 cd src/main/java
 javac com/zerovector/app/App.java
```

If you follow this rule, the package declaration and the relative path to the Java source file match and everything works. If you change your current directory to the place where the Java Source file is, then the compiler expects no package (= default package):

```
cd src/main/java/com/zerovector/app/
javac App.java
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise, expedient response.